# How to write a function that will handle multiple onclick events which toggle the visibility of a field

Tags: javascript, function, button

Ive not been coding long and I am new to javascript. Im making a simple web page that will show and hide part of a sentence for the purposes of learning foreign language. Is there a way to write one function that when a button is clicked it shows and hides the field.

If I use document.getElementsByClassName() and iterate through each button and get an array of buttons, I don't understand how I feed that array of buttons into one function tat performs the showing and hiding similar to this function below. (I know the below is using getElementById) but im trying to do the same thing but with document.getElementsByClassName().

```
const a = document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener( "click" , function(){
  if(document.getElementById("para1").style.visibility === "hidden"){
    document.getElementById("para1").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("para1").style.visibility ="hidden";
  }
```

Ive looked at the questions already on here but they seem very advanced for what i'm trying to do. I know this is simple stuff but any help would be appreciated.

Ive tried the above as explained but I just can't seem to find an example of how to connect one function to multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the event bubbling mechanism https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

1. Put the event to a top level container
2. Find the button when the event have triggered
3. Get an toggling element's id
4. Switch visibility

```
// https://jsfiddle.net/shiningfinger/b5uxcwpo/4/

const getControlElement = (element) => {
    if (
        element.tagName === "A" ||
        element.tagName === "BUTTON" ||
        (element.tagName === "INPUT" &&
            (element.type === "submit" || element.type === "button"))
    ) {
        return element;
    }

    const { parentElement } = element;
    if (!parentElement) return false;
    return getControlElement(parentElement);
};

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const controlElement = getControlElement(event.target);
    // put element id to data-toggling-element-id attribute
    const { togglingElementId } = controlElement.dataset;
    const togglingElement = document.getElementById(togglingElementId);

    if (!togglingElement) return;

    togglingElement.style.visibility =
        togglingElement.style.visibility !== "hidden" ? "hidden" : "visible";
});
```